# How to Format Date you get from backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I put in my mongoose Schema the `createdDate` for every new person that needs to be created and shown in the table but can not be changed so i did it in mongoose schema. But when i get the date on the frontend to put it in the table i first map. all the items in js elements and when i call the date in other file where my table is with props.date i cant format my date on no way to be like dd/MM/yyyy or anything similar to that instead i get like `2020-11-13T12:37:05.637Z`.  Can someone pls help me the way of how to formate the date I get from props and from the database.

This is where i call the date from props.

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {error && <Errormsg error={error} />}
      <tbody className="table">
        <tr>
          <td>{props.id}</td>
          <td>{props.name}</td>
          <td>{props.surname}</td>
          <td>{props.city}</td>
          <td>{props.address}</td>
          <td>{props.phone}</td>
          <td>{props.date}</td>
          <td>
            <Button>
              <Link to={`/person/${props.id}`}>Edit</Link>
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And this is where i map it once i got it from the backend.

```
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>SURNAME</th>
          <th>CITY</th>
          <th>ADDRESS</th>
          <th>PHONE</th>
          <th>CREATED DATE</th>
          <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {props.items.map((person) => (
        <PersonItems
          key={person.id}
          id={person.id}
          name={person.name}
          surname={person.surname}
          city={person.city}
          address={person.address}
          phone={person.phone}
          date={person.createdDate}
          onDelete={props.onDeletePerson}
        />
      ))}
         </table>
  );
};
```

And this is my schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  surname: { type: String, required: true },
  city: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: Number, required: true },
  createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Persons", personSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for that

To get your desired result you can use it like this

```
 <td>{moment(props.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</td>
```

Just add the above line whereever you want to display the date in this format.

The benefit of this approach is that you can change the format exactly to your needs by changing the format string.

Comment: @Stefan Great, please consider marking the answer as the accepted answer to help future users

Answer (score 0):

try `new Date('2020-11-13T12:37:05.637Z').toLocaleString()` the output will be like `11/13/2020, 2:37:05 PM`

if you used then split function like `new Date('2020-11-13T12:37:05.637Z').toLocaleString().split(',')[0]` you will get `11/13/2020` which is what you need from what i understand

If you want to use another package for it , you should definitely use moment.js

Answer (score 0):

install `moment` package -  `npm install moment --save`

```
import moment from "moment";

 <td>{moment(props.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</td>
```

Sample Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-antonelli-4r1qw?file=/src/App.js:200-257

Answer (score 0):

One option (to avoid momentjs) is to use the Intl API:

```
const date = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat).formatToParts(new Date("01-01-80"))
console.log(`${date1[0].value}/${date1[2].value}/${date1[4].value}`)
// outputs 01/01/80
```

Answer (score 0):

- the solution for this problem is :
- you need to download a thrid party package called `moment`
- If you are using it in `reactjs`
- you can import it as

```
import moment from "moment";

<p> Ordered on : {moment(order.createdAt).fromNow()} </p>
```

- you can also use a third party package called `dayjs`

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

<p >{dayjs(createdAt).fromNow()}</p>
```